# Performance - Plot with Calloutmarker ->"Arrow" and ImageSize->Full

Tags: plotting, manipulate, output-formatting, formatting, legending

This is a little esoteric, but I noticed that using `CalloutMarker -> "Arrow"` on a `Plot` that uses `ImageSize->Full` causes huge performance problems (minutes vs fractions of a second) if `Manipulate` is used.

A minimal example to produce the behavior is shown below:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[
  Callout[x, "x", CalloutMarker -> "Arrow"],
  {x, 0, 1},
  ImageSize -> Full
  ],
 {a}
 ]
```

I am using version 12.1.1.

For now, I'll just use a `CalloutMarker` other than "Arrow", but does anybody have a workaround that accomplishes the intent of the above code, without taking forever?

Comment: same issue with `CalloutMarker -> Arrowheads[Medium]`  and `CalloutMarker -> Arrowheads[.02]`. (Version 11.3.0 Windows 10-64b)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same issue arises when we use `CalloutMarker -> Arrowheads[Medium]` or `CalloutMarker -> Arrowheads[.02]` in combination with `Manipulate` and`ImageSize -> Full`.

A simple fix is to use `ImageSize -> Scaled[1]` instead of `ImageSize -> Full`:

```
Manipulate[Plot[Callout[x, "x", CalloutMarker -> "Arrow"], {x, 0, 1}, 
  ImageSize -> Scaled[1]], {a}]
```

[image]

```
$Version
```

> "11.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)"